# R Distributed Clustering Package

Tags: r

Are there any existing R clustering packages (kmeans, hierarchical) that utilizes RHadoop or RHIPE to run on distributed hadoop clusters?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[RevolutionAnalytics / RHadoop](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki) implementation of the RHadoop Project packages connects Hadoop and R via rhdfs, rhbase and rmr.

I know that implementing K-means clustering algorithm the "standard" way (using Python, Pig and Java, as shown on slides 8-10) compared to using just R (with the rmr package, shown on slides 14-15): it takes much less code, and can be implemented in a single language

In the same documentation there is an [comparison implementation of K-means in Python, Java and R](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki/Comparison-of-high-level-languages-for-mapreduce%3a-k-means) which shows how easy it is using R.

IF you run this package on your Hadoop cluster you sure can write K-means clustering on Hadoop.

IF R is not your choice then K-means clustering (build using MapReduce) is available on Hadoop and Mahout so you sure can do it on Hadoop clusters.